# regex match all not PDF files

Tags: php, regex

`preg_match('/\.(?!pdf)$/', $file)`

I want to match all files except pdf files

```
path/file.jpg # match
path/file.png # match
path/file.pdf # not match
```

Comment: if the file has a name like `path/pdf_file.png`

Comment: match all files except pdf files

Comment: `\.(?!pdf$).+$`

Comment: @splash58 Please avoid posting answers as comments; it makes it harder to find, and impossible to edit, vote on, etc

Comment: You should not use all the recommended complicated regular expressions below. Use `$(?<!\.pdf)` instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using regex, you can take the extension of your file and check if it's a pdf.

```
$ext = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if($ext != 'pdf'){
    echo "I'm not a pdf";
}
```

If you prefer using regex

```
<?php
$file = array("path/file.jpg", "path/file.png", "path/file.pdf");
foreach ($file as &$value) {
    preg_match('/^(.(?!.*\.pdf$))*$/', $value, $matches);
    if(!empty($matches)){
        echo " $value is not a pdf";
    }
}
```

https://regex101.com/r/7C7YsR/1

Comment: I prefer regex..

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use a regex, this one will work:

```
^(?!.*\.pdf).*$
```

It simply uses a negative lookahead to assert that the filename doesn't end in `.pdf` and then `.*` to match everything in the filename.

[Demo on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/uCnapj/1)

In PHP:

```
$filenames = array('path/file.jpg','path/file.png','path/file.pdf');
foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
    if (preg_match('/^(?!.*\.pdf).*$/', $filename)) echo "\"$filename\" is not a PDF file.\n";
}
```

Output:

```
"path/file.jpg" is not a PDF file. 
"path/file.png" is not a PDF file.
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/5HusD)

Answer (score 0):

Asserting that something is *not* present in a regex is often fiddly, because a regex works by looking through the input for things to match.

The approach you've used is a "zero-width negative look-ahead assertion" - it matches anywhere in the string that isn't followed by `pdf`, *but doesn't "use up" any input*. So your regex doesn't work because the rest of it still needs to match, and that is `/\.$/`, meaning "`.` at end of string".

The simplest approach is to look for strings that *do* end `.pdf`, e.g. `if ( ! preg_match('/\.pdf$/', $file) ) { ... }`.